# ¿Cómo hacer un contador de caracteres repetidos de un array dentro de una función en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Tengo una función que contiene un array y necesito contar caracteres o números repetidos dentro de este array y eliminar las comas que separan a los caracteres o números, todo esto dentro de JavaScript. Solo consigo un error que se excedió el tamaño de la pila de llamadas.
Tengo algo así en mi código:

````
function DistinctList(arr)//aquí el array contiene esto [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
{
   const num = null;
   n =  DistinctList(arr).replace(/,/g,'');//aquí convierto a cadena y quito todas las comas
   var parecidos= 0;
   var revisados = [];
   var caracteresRepetidos = function(str) 
   {
                
    for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++) 
    {
       
       if (!revisados.includes(str[i]) && str.indexOf(str[i]) !== str.lastIndexOf(str[i])) 
       {
         revisados.push(str[i]);
         ocurencias = ocurencias+1;
       }
    }
    return parecidos;
   }
        return(caracteresRepetidos(n) );
}
   console.log(DistinctList(readline()));// la salida o resultado debe ser 3 ya que se repite el número 2 una vez y se repite el número 5 dos veces dentro del array ```
````

Comment: Creo haber visto una pregunta similar hace un tiempo.

Comment: Y cúal es la salida esperada? Un valor numérico? Qué representa este valor? La cantidad de caracteres que aparecen más de una vez en el Array de entrada? Para la siguiente entrada: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, ¿cuál será la salida? `0`? Podrías aclarar esto?

Comment: @MauricioContreras la salida o resultado debe ser 3 ya que se repite el número 2 una vez y se repite el número 5 dos veces dentro del array

Answer (score 2):

Aquí el error:

```
n =  DistinctList(arr).replace(/,/g,'');
```

Si quieres convertir a cadena y quitar todas las comas, puedes hacerlo con el método [**`join()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```
n = arr.join('').replace(/,/g, '');
```

#### Demo:

```js
function DistinctList(arr) {
  // const num = null; // Nunca se utiliza.
  var n = arr.join('').replace(/,/g, ''); // Convierto al array en cadena y devuelve => "122333"
  var parecidos = 0;
  var revisados = [];
  var caracteresRepetidos = function (str) {

    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

      if (!revisados.includes(str[i]) && str.indexOf(str[i]) !== str.lastIndexOf(str[i])) {
        revisados.push(str[i]);
        // ocurencias = ocurencias + 1; // "ocurrencias" no existe.
        parecidos++; // preferible hacerlo así.
      }
    }
    return parecidos;
  }
  return (caracteresRepetidos(n));
}
console.log(DistinctList([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]));
```

---

Respecto a tu [última observación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/594291/c%C3%B3mo-hacer-un-contador-de-caracteres-repetidos-de-un-array-dentro-de-una-funci%C3%B3#comment1050289_594291), te daré una posible solución:

- En tu array, podemos filtrar solo los elementos que se repiten (excepto el elemento actual).
- Para esto, nos podemos apoyar del elemento actual y de su índice, utilizándolos como argumentos del `filter()`.
- Condicionamos que si el índice actual es diferente del índice de la primera aparición del elemento. Si cumple, quiere decir que el elemento está repetido en el array, ya que se encontró otra aparición del mismo elemento en un índice diferente al actual.

Teniendo en cuenta esto, tendríamos el siguiente código:

```
let repetidos = arr.filter(function (elem, index) {
  return arr.indexOf(elem) !== index;
});
```

Para que se entienda mejor, hagamos un ejemplo con el array `[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]`:

- El elemento `1` se encuentra en el índice `0`.
- El elemento `2` se encuentra en el índice `1`, pero también hay otra aparición del `2` en el índice `2`.
- El elemento `3` se encuentra en el índice `3`, pero hay otras dos apariciones del `3` en los índices `4` y `5`.

Entonces, al comparar el índice actual (que es `index`) con el índice de la primera aparición (que es `arr.indexOf(elem)`), sabremos si un elemento está repetido o no en el array. Y en el caso de los elementos que se repiten, estos tienen un índice diferente al de su primera aparición en el array (del mismo elemento), lo que indica que están repetidos, ya que la condición cumple y se incluirá en el `filter()`.

#### Demo:

```js
function DistinctList(arr) {
  let repetidos = arr.filter(function (elem, index) {
    // filter() se ejecuta para cada elemento del array. El primer argumento,
    // "elem", representa el elemento actual en cada iteración, mientras que el
    // segundo argumento, "index", representa el índice del elemento actual.

    // Aquí verificamos si el índice del elemento actual ("elem") en el array
    // es diferente del índice de la primera aparición del elemento en el array.
    // Si los índices son diferentes, significa que el elemento está repetido en el
    // array y se incluye en el resultado del filter().
    return arr.indexOf(elem) !== index;
  });

  // y como filter devuelve un array, obtenemos su longitud => "[2, 3, 3]" => 3
  return repetidos.length;
}

console.log(DistinctList([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]));
```

```js
function DistinctList(arr) {
  let repetidos = arr.filter(function (elem, index) {
    return arr.indexOf(elem) !== index;
  });
  
  return repetidos.length;
}

console.log(DistinctList([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]));
```

Comment: Gracias me sirve en lo que encuentro como indexar desde el valor o posición 0

Comment: @JPPdlM recuerda verificar la respuesta marcandole al ✔️ si te sirvió, si tienes alguna otra duda más me avisas.

Answer (score 2):

Gracias a la aclaración aportada en tu [último comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/594291/como-hacer-un-contador-de-caracteres-repetidos-de-un-array-dentro-de-una-funcio?noredirect=1#comment1050289_594291), y viendo que las otras respuestas no se ajustan al requerimiento, te dejo esta posible solución.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea calcular cuántas veces en total aparecen repetidos los valores de una lista de números.

Por ejemplo, dada la siguiente entrada:

```js
const valores = [ 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3];
```

El resultado esperado es `3`, ya que de la lista se tiene:

- El valor `1` se repite 0 veces
- El valor `2` se repite 1 vez
- El valor `3` se repite 2 veces.

La suma de las repticiones de cada valor de la lista es: `3`.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Una posible solución es recorrer la lista de elementos y por cada elemento contar las repeticiones, sin embargo el desafío es saber si el elemento que se está recorriendo ya fue contado con anterioridad.

Entonces, una opción es crear un objeto que guarde como clave el elemento que se recorre y cuyo valor sea la cantidad de veces que el elemento se repite en la lista. El valor inicial de cada elemento siempre será 0 (no tiene repeticiones) y por cada repetición se suma una unidad al valor almacenado.

Para lograrlo, usaremos un objeto que inicializamos sin elementos y actualizaremos dicho objeto en cada iteración durante el recorrido de la lista de elementos.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const valores = [ 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3];
const repeticiones = {};
valores.forEach(valor => {
  if(!Object.keys(repeticiones).includes(valor.toString())) {
    repeticiones[valor.toString()] = 0;
  } else {
    repeticiones[valor.toString()] += 1;
  }
});
console.log(repeticiones);
const total = Object.values(repeticiones).reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr);
console.log(total);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

En este ejemplo hemos usado los siguientes métodos del [Objeto Global Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) y del [Objeto Global Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object):

- [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes): que devuelve un valor verdadero si el elemento a buscar existe en el Array.
- [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce): ejecuta una función reductora sobre cada elemento de un array, devolviendo como resultado un único valor.
- [`keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys): devuelve un arreglo de propiedades enumerables propias de un objeto dado.
- [`values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values): devuelve un array con los valores correspondientes a las propiedades enumerables de un objeto.

En el caso de tu pregunta, dado que requires una función que recibe una lista de elementos y devuelve la cantidad de repeticiones totales de los elementos de la lista, puedes escribir algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```js
function DistinctList(arr) {
  const rep = {};
  arr.forEach(item => {
    if(!Object.keys(rep).includes(item.toString())) {
      rep[item.toString()] = 0;
    } else {
      rep[item.toString()] += 1;
    }
  });
  return Object.values(rep).reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr);
}
const valores1 = [ 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3];
const valores2 = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const valores3 = [ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2];
console.log(DistinctList(valores1)); // 3
console.log(DistinctList(valores2)); // 0
console.log(DistinctList(valores3)); // 5
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Gracias pero los constantes con valores recuerda que llegan llenos desde el "arr" que contiene: "[1, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5]" más no se los paso por variable esa ya está llena y al final no puede imprimir o mostrar el DisstincList :(

Comment: @JPPdlM la verdad no entiendo tu comentario. Lo siento.

Answer (score 1):

Más que una corrección, te ofrezco una alternativa:

```js
function DistinctList(arr) {
    let elementos = new Map();

    // Se quitan las comas
    arr = arr.filter(char => char != ",");

    // Se cuentan las veces que aparece cada elemento
    arr.forEach(char => elementos.set(char, (elementos.get(char) ?? 0) + 1));
    // O si de esta forma se entiende mejor
    // arr.forEach(char => elementos.set(char, elementos.has(char) ? elementos.get(char) + 1 : 1));

    // Si no se quitan las comas previamente, también
    // se pueden quitar las luego de contarlas
    // elementos.delete(",");

    // La función 'values' devuelve un iterador.
    // Es necesario convertirlo en un arreglo para poder usar 'reduce'
    return Array.from(elementos.values()).reduce((acc, veces) => acc + veces - 1, 0);
}
console.log(DistinctList([1, ",", 2, ",", 2, 3, 3, 3]));
```

Puedes consultar la documentación de [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) y [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: Gracias por la posible solución, disculpa mi ignorancia pero aún estoy tratando de entender algunos fragmentos del código como el acc y el veces hehe.

Comment: @JPPdlM la función en `reduce` devuelve un valor. El primer parámetro contiene el último valor devuelto o si es la primera vez que se ejecuta, contiene 0, ese mismo que está al final de la línea. El segundo parámetro es un elemento del arreglo. Puedes consultar [la documentación de `reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) para entenderlo mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Colaboro con una versión más básica...

```js
function DistinctList( arr ) {
   var revisados = arr[ 0 ] + "";  
   let entrada = revisados; 
   var repetidos = "";
   let cantidad = 0;
   for( var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++ ) {  
       let numero = arr[ i ];
       entrada += numero;
       if( ! revisados.includes( numero ) ) {   
           revisados += " " + numero;              
       } 
       else {
           cantidad++;               
       }
    }
    return cantidad + " " + entrada;
}

console.log( DistinctList( [ 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3 ] ));

Gracias a @Mauricio Contreras que tuvo la genial idea de hacer la pregunta más básica de todas, "que salida se espera?", hice la corrección pertinente.
```